# Calling variable in user-defined function with reshape2::melt and reshape2::dcast

Tags: r, function, reshape2

I would like to convert this data frame

```
data <- data.frame(color=c("red","red","red","green","green","green","blue","blue","blue"),object=c("box","chair","table","box","chair","table","box","chair","table"),units=c(1:9),price=c(11.5,12.5,13.5,14.5,15.5,16.5,17.5,18.5,19.5))
```

to this other one

```
output <- data.frame(color=c("red","green","blue"),units_box=c(1,4,7),price_box=c(11.5,14.5,17.5), units_chair=c(2,5,8),price_chair=c(12.5,15.5,18.5),units_table=c(3,6,9),price_table=c(13.5,16.5,19.5))
```

Therefore, I am using `reshape2::melt` and `reshape2::dcast` to build a user-defined function as the following

```
fun<-function(df,var,group){
  r<-reshape2::melt(df,id.vars=var)
  r<-reshape2::dcast(r,var~group) 
return(r)
}
```

When I use the function as follows

fun(data,color,object)

I get the following error message

> Error in melt_check(data, id.vars, measure.vars, variable.name,
>   value.name) : object 'color' not found

Do you know how can I solve it? I think that the problem is that I should call the variables in `reshape2::melt` with quotes but I do not know how.

Note 1: I would like keep the original number format of variables (i.e. objects without decimals and price with one decimal)

Note 2: I would like to remark that that my real code (this is just a simplified example) is much longer and involves `dplyr` functions (including enquo() and UQ() functions). Therefore the solutions for this case should be compatible with `dplyr`.

Note 3: I do not use tidyr (I am a big fun of the whole tidyverse) because the current `tidyr` still use the old language for functions and I share the script with other people that might not be willing to use the development version of `tidyr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by myself (although I do not know very well the reasons behind).
The main problem, as I suspected was passing the variables of the user-defined function in melt and dcast cause some kind of conflict maybe due to the lack of quotes (?). 
Anyway I renamed the variables using dplyr::rename so that the names are not anymore depended of variables but characters. Here you can see the final code I am applying:

```
fun<-function(df,var,group){
  enquo_var<-enquo(var)
  enquo_group<-enquo(group)

  r<-df%>%
    reshape2::melt(., id.var=1, variable.name = "parameter")%>%
    dplyr::rename(var = UQ(enquo_var))%>%
    reshape2::dcast(data=., formula = var~parameter, value.var = "value")

return(r)
}

funx<-fun(data,color,object)
```

Although I found the solution to my particular problem, I would appreciate very much if someone explains me the reasons behind.

PS: I hope anyway that the new version of tidyr is ready soon to make such tasks easier. Thanks @hadley for your fantastic work.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(data), color ~object, value.var = c("units", "price"), FUN = c(length, mean))
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, @akrun but I get the same error message `Error in melt.data.table(df, id.vars = var) : object 'color' not found` when using the function as follows `fun<-function(df,var,group){

  r<-reshape2::melt(df,id.vars=var)
  r<-dcast(setDT(r), color ~object, value.var = c("units", "price"), FUN = c(length, mean))

return(r)
}

fun(data,color,object)`

Comment: @ungatoverde  I am not getting any error with your example using `data.table_1.10.5`  Oh okay, based on your function, where is `data` in the `fun`.  I see that you have created an object `r`

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I had a mistake in my previous comment. I just corrected it. I also add proper function names of data.table:  
 
`fun<-function(df,var,group){  r<-data.table::melt.data.table(df,id.vars=var)
  r<-data.table::dcast.data.table(setDT(r), color ~object, value.var = c("units", "price"), FUN = c(length, mean))

return(r)
}

fun(data,color,object)` but still the same error message :-(

Comment: @ungatoverde  I don't understand the `melt` here.  Your `data` seems to be already in the `long` format.  Could you show the input data used

Comment: the input data is the first data frame provided in my question: `data <- data.frame(color=c("red","red","red","green","green","green","blue","blue","blue"),object=c("box","chair","table","box","chair","table","box","chair","table"),units=c(1:9),price=c(11.5,12.5,13.5,14.5,15.5,16.5,17.5,18.5,19.5))`

Comment: My input data has two columns for values and I assume I need to have only one column (melt) with values to apply `dcast`